# How do you draw a particular glyph using Java on Android?

Tags: java, android, glyph

I have seen http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/font/GlyphVector.html but I don't know how you would use it to display a glyph on the screen. Lets say you want to print glyph number 1042 (likely to be different in each font and unlikely (but possible) to be the same as Unicode 1042) to the screen. How do you go from the number to the character on screen? Is GlyphVector the way to go or is there a better method?

Answer (score 0):

That GlyphVector class is not available on Android. There don’t seem to be any public API calls in Android graphics that allow access to font glyphs without going through the Unicode encoding.

Your obvious option would seem to be direct parsing of the TrueType font file. Perhaps find some library somewhere that has been ported to Android, or could be so ported (Freetype?).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any way to add this class to an Android project? I need to print the glyphs directly because the Unicode encoding doesn't handle complex scripts, at least on Android 2.*. Alternatively, can a custom Unicode encoder be added?